# Why is pg_table_def table returning tablenames containing the text "_$mig"

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am using `pg_table_def` to work out the primary keys associated to a given table, example below:

```
SELECT pg_table_def.tablename,
       pg_table_def.column
FROM pg_table_def
WHERE schemaname = 'myschema'
AND   tablename LIKE '%mytable%'
AND   tablename LIKE '%_pkey%';
```

Example output from the above query:

```
tablename          column
mytable_$mig_pkey  id
```

This is correctly identifying the primary keys, but in some cases the format of the tablename returned has the text `_$mig` in it, for example: `mytable_$mig_pkey`.

I use the tablename in a later part of the code so currently have to remove this text. My questions are:

- Why for some tables is the tablename formatted like this with `_$mig`?
- Are there other strings that could appear between `tablename` and `_pkey` that should be taken into consideration?
- Or is there a better way to identify the primary keys associated to a
  table?

I've so far tried:

- Checking the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PG_TABLE_DEF.html) it recommends to check the search_path, so I've done this and made sure the schema is referenced in the where clause.
- Checked that `mytable_$mig` doesn't exist / isn't available.
- Other googling hasn't got me any further...

**Update**

Based on the comments below, running the below query:

```
select tablename, "column", type, encoding, distkey, sortkey, "notnull"
from pg_table_def
where schemaname = 'myschema' AND tablename LIKE '%mytable%';
```

Returns:

```
tablename         column type                  encoding distkey sortkey notnull
mytable           id     integer               none     true    1       true
mytable           desc   character varying(50) lzo      false   0       false
mytable_$mig_pkey id      integer               none     true    1       false
```

Comment: What client are you using? With psql, does your table name show up correctly using `\d`?

Comment: Also I'm guessing the last line of your query should be `AND "column" like '%_pkey'`?

Comment: I'm using sql workbench to connect to redshift. Not sure what you are referring to regarding adding `\d` - could you explain more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

So it looks like you have your actual table and one that was probably created accidentally. If you do `select count(*) from mytable` and `select count(*) from mytable_$mig_pkey;`, hopefully mytable has all your data and the other one is 
empty. If so you can clean it up with `drop table mytable_$mig_pkey`.

I see you have the `id` column as the distkey which is Redshift's version of a primary key. You may also be trying to define constraints, which Redshift will allow you to do, but they are [not enforced](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Defining_constraints.html).

You can view the defined table constraints for a table like so:

```
select * from information_schema.table_constraints 
where table_name='mytable';
```

On one of my tables gives a result like:

```
 constraint_catalog | constraint_schema | constraint_name | table_catalog | table_schema | table_name | constraint_type | is_deferrable | initially_deferred
 --------------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+---------------+--------------------
        mydb      | myschema         | mytable_pkey         | mydb | myschema    | mytable         | PRIMARY KEY     | NO            | NO
  (1 row)
```

My current guess is that you attempted to define constraints on your table and accidentally created a second table at some point, which is why the other table has `_pkey` in its name.

---

I use a query like this myself:

```
select tablename, "column", type, encoding, distkey, sortkey, "notnull"
from pg_table_def
where schemaname = 'myschema' AND tablename LIKE '%mytable%';
```

Running something more general like that might help you figure out what's going on.

The `\d` I referenced in the comments is a way to list all the tables in the database that is a convenience function built into the [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/app-psql.html) command line app. The query it runs to do that is this:

```
SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
  c.relname as "Name",
  CASE c.relkind WHEN 'r' THEN 'table' WHEN 'v' THEN 'view' WHEN 'm' THEN 'materialized view' WHEN 'i' THEN 'index' WHEN 'S' THEN 'sequence' WHEN 's' THEN 'special' WHEN 'f' THEN 'foreign table' END as "Type",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(c.relowner) as "Owner"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE c.relkind IN ('r','v','m','S','f','')
      AND n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
      AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
      AND n.nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
  AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Running that might help.

Comment: thanks for the comments. I also ran the second query you shared to list all tables in the db, but this table, `mytable_$mig_pkey`, wasn't returned.

Comment: I will investigate about whether it was caused by a script or function...